# Use inline function in subquery (in a WHERE clause)

Tags: oracle, subquery, with-statement, oracle19c, inline-functions

In a [COTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commercial_off-the-shelf) system, I am able to enter a [SQL WHERE clause](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/mam/7.6.0?topic=as-sql-where-clause-searches).

Example of WHERE clauses that work:

```
worktype = 'Corrective Maintenance'
```

or

```
1 = (
    with 
        cte as (select 1 as calc from dual)
    select 
        calc 
    from 
        cte
    )
```

---

Similarly, I'm wondering if it's possible to use an **inline function** in a subquery in a WHERE clause.

This inline function works on it's own in an SQL client:

```
with 
    function inline_f(p_num number) return number is 
    begin
        return p_num + 0;
    end;
select 
    inline_f(1) as calc 
from 
    dual

Calc
----
1
```

But if I were to wrap it in a subquery in a WHERE clause, then I'd get an error (in the COTS system and even in an SQL client):

```
--select * from a_tbl where

1 = (
    with 
        function inline_f(p_num number) return number is 
        begin
            return p_num + 0;
        end;
    select 
        inline_f(1) as calc 
    from 
        dual
    )

ORA-00921: unexpected end of SQL command
Invalid statement
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

---

Question:

Is there a way to use an inline function in subquery (in a WHERE clause)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to use an inline function in subquery (in a WHERE
> clause)?

There is, but I am not sure if this will help you. I don't know what a COTS system is, and how it works. I understand that users can only enter a `WHERE` clause; but do you (as a developer) - or whoever the developer is, if it's not you - have access to the entire `SELECT` statement?

If the query in which you define a function in the `WITH` clause is not the top-level `SELECT` statement (in your case it isn't), then the top-level `SELECT` must include the **`with_plsql`** hint. (Oracle calls it a "hint", anyway; it uses the hint syntax, but it's not a hint, it is really a compiler directive.) Alas, this **must** be in the top-level `SELECT` (meaning the `SELECT` clause of your query, which is not accessible by your end user).

This is why I asked... if whoever develops these queries for your users doesn't mind adding the `with_plsql` hint to the top-level `SELECT`, then you can do what you asked. The hint won't hurt anything if a user types a `WHERE` clause with no PL/SQL code in a `WITH` clause, so there should be no reason not to want to do this; but, like I said, I don't know what COTS means or how it works.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan - as the answer says, it must be at the top level - [then it works](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d514e500e01ad5b35402029952838b8e).

Comment: COTS = Commercial, Off-the-shelf. (They've paid for a commercial software package and have not customised it.)

Comment: @MT0 - I found out as much (Google works), but I still don't know what that means. PeopleSoft, for example, would be COTS (I assume). Some places take the view that it can't be touched for any reason, while others use Oracle-provided tools to make changes to what comes out of the box. Can the OP do that? That's what I meant.